# ORA-01747 when trying to persist two entities with ontoone relation

Tags: java, oracle, entity-framework, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to persist 2 entities linked together in ONE TO ONE relation however I'm getting the error from bellow:

```
 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
Error Code: 1747
Call: INSERT INTO FLIGHT (ID, DATE, FLIGHTDESTINATION, FLIGHTORIGIN, PRICE, airplane_fk) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
```

Flight Entity:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="airplane_fk")
private Airplane airplaneDetail;
```

Airplane Entity

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="airplaneDetail")
private Flight flight;
```

The persistence will be made via a controller servlet injected with a Stateless Bean that contains the Persistence Manager for the 2 entities.

Can you please help me with some piece of advice.

Regards,

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved word in Oracle SQL

Comment: Simply rename field to `FLIGHT_DATE`